# Etymology of でしょう?

Tags: etymology

Does anyone know what でしょう originally comes from?

And are those forms ever used nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

だ and です are modern contracted copulae (verbs "to be"), they developed in Late Middle Japanese.

だろう and でしょう are Conjectural/Tentative forms of these copulae, formed slightly irregularly.

Old Japanese suffix *-(a)m-* is called Conjectural by Frellesvig (2010), Tentative by Vovin (2020).

Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", page 78) in chapter about Old Japanese:

> 3.1.4.10 Conjectural and subjunctive
>
> The *conjectural* belongs to the QD conjugation. The *subjunctive* has its own conjugation, the few forms of which resemble the simple past.
>
> The conjectural is the least specific of the modal auxiliaries and is very frequent in the OJ texts. Its uses fall into two overall categories: (a) *conjecture*: probability and necessity; (b) *volition*: intention and wish. Note that the combination of the simple past and the conjectural *-kye-m-* is used only to express conjecture 'probably was, probably did', not volition. Like modals in many languages, the conjectural can also be used to refer to future time with little or no modal meaning; the conjectural is therefore sometimes termed a 'future tense'. Followed by the conjunctional particles *to* or *ni* it is used to form purposive adjunct and complement clauses 'that, so that'.

Highly defective simple copula was/is [*nə* (*no* since EMJ), *ni*, *nite* (→ LMJ/NJ *de*)]. Since it was defective, it did not have many forms, and it participated/participates in constructions with other verbs (*ar(i|u)*, *imasu*), which allow full inflection. <sub>(That verb [*imasu*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99), now archaic or extinct, should not be mistaken with *-masu* form of modern verb *iru*, which comes from OJ/EMJ *wiru*.)</sub>

Main extended copula in Old Japanese and at least Early Middle Japanese was formed with verb *ar(i|u)*: ***ni ar(i|u)***, and its contracted form ***nar(i|u)***.

Conjectural/Tentative form of copula *ni ar(i|u)* / *nar(i|u)* in Old Japanese and early Early Middle Japanese was: ***ni aramu*** / ***naramu***.

In Late Middle Japanese, extended copula ***de aru*** developed. It contains the same verb *aru* (earlier *ar(i|u)*) as older aforementioned *ni ar(i|u)* / *nar(i|u)*, but contains different form of defective simple copula: *de* instead of *ni*. Modern copula ***da*** developed as contraction of ***de aru***.

There were/are other similar constructions in LMJ/NJ, e.g. ***de gozaru*** (currently used in samurai-style speech).

One of now extinct constructions was with verb *s[ɔ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel)ːrɔː*: ***de sɔːrɔː***.
Modern polite copula ***desu*** is considered (by at least some linguists) to be contraction of ***de sɔːrɔː***.

---

Phonological development of Conjectural/Tentative suffix ***-am-*** + Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい} *-u*:

- For consonant-stem verbs:

  /-amu/ → /-a[ũ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_vowel)/ → /-au/ → /-[ɔ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel)ː/ → /-[o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_rounded_vowel)ː/

  Example for *kaku* (書く):

  /kakamu/ → /kakaũ/ → /kakau/ → /kakɔː/ → /kakoː/
- For *e*-vowel-stem verbs (initial *a* of *-amu* suffix was elided):

  /-emu/ → /-eũ/ → /-eu/ → /-<sup>j</sup>oː/ → (regularization) /-ejoː/

  Example for Old/Middle Japanese *nu*, modern 寝る:

  /nemu/ → /neũ/ → /neu/ → /n<sup>j</sup>oː/ → (regularization) /nejoː/
- For *i*-vowel-stem verbs (initial *a* of *-amu* suffix was elided):

  /-imu/ → /-iũ/ → /-iu/ → /-<sup>j</sup>uː/ → (regularization) /-ijoː/

  Example for Old Japanese *mi*, Middle Japanese *miru*, modern 見る:

  /mimu/ → /miũ/ → /miu/ → /m<sup>j</sup>uː/ → (regularization) /mijoː/
- For irregular vowel-stem verbs (initial *a* of *-amu* suffix was elided):

  Verb *kə-* → *ko-* (Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい} *ku*, modern *kuru* (来る)):

  /kəmu/ → /komu/ → /koũ/ → /kou/ → /koː/ → (regularization) /kojoː/

  Verb *se-* (Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい} *su*, modern *suru* (する)):

  /semu/ → /seũ/ → /seu/ → /s<sup>j</sup>oː/ → (regularization) /sijoː/

Forms with nasal vowel /ũ/ existed for some time in Early Middle Japanese. During this period, there were also other variants of development of original /mu/, which ultimately did not survive.

Fusion of consecutive vowels into long vowels occurred in Late Middle Japanese and was not specific to this suffix, it occurred also in many other words.

Europeans arrived to Japan in 16th century, and distinction between 2 types of long vowel *o*, assumed to be [low-mid /ɔː/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel) and [high-mid /oː/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_rounded_vowel), is attested in European sources about Japanese language from 16th/17th century. /ɔː/ and /oː/ merged into /oː/ in Early Modern Japanese.

Regularization of forms of this suffix for vowel-stem verbs occurred in Modern Japanese (maybe middle/late Edo period).

---

When ***desu*** appeared, we would rather expect that its Conjectural/Tentative form be ****/desɔː/*** (＊でさう) → ****/desoː/*** (＊でそう), but ***/des<sup>j</sup>oː/*** (modern hiragana spelling でしょう) was created probably by analogy with Conjectural/Tentative form of verb す／する, which was /s<sup>j</sup>oː/ at that time.

Comment: なろほどねーありがとうございます